# Media Queries issue: Seems to be igorning main styles on desktop

Tags: css, wordpress, media-queries, desktop

Got some weird stuff going on. Trying to fix up an old WordPress theme which was never designed for mobile and I found issues once I added media queries. They seem to be what I want overall on mobile devices but once I hit desktop, everything looks messed up as if it's adapting to the mobile media queries and I'm really confused as to why. Am I supposed to add something to the desktop styles to make this work overall? Here's my site in question: http://destinationbeershow.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you have

```
<body class="mobile">
```

at your mobile version and you specify the `.mobile` in all your rules affecting only mobile, then I guess you will be out of the woods.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to clarify with at least one or two examples of the specific problems you're encountering, but just looking at one or two elements, remember some basic CSS rules.

1. When using media queries, any rules meeting the conditions will be triggered.
2. Rules overwrite each other top to bottom, which means whatever is listed last will be the property used.
3. If you're encountering problems when your rules look different, remember that whether CSS rules overwrite each other depends on a rule's specificity. (This is more of a side note, but important to remember. See this article on [calculating CSS specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) if this is a problem you're encountering.)

For example:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #content {
    width: 656px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  #content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Once the viewport (browser window size) is 480px your element with id="content" will be 100% width. Then, when your viewport is 768px, it will still be 100% width, because the second rule is overwriting the first one since both rules are true.

If you want rules to override the smaller media query rule, then you have to make sure your larger size media query comes after. For example:

```
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  #content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #content {
    width: 656px;
  }
}
```

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: So you can't use px for one width and % for another and expect to get away with it?

Comment: @AdamBell clearly I missed a step in my explanation. Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Actually, i just solved it. I had min-width for those elements when I meant to use max-width. Duh! I think I'm out of the woods.